# Input values not populated in form object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a directive which contains a form.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="GroupForm" ng-submit="addNew(GroupForm)" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block">
            <i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-in"></i>Create
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Now the directive is an element.

```
{
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: 'true',

            templateUrl: '/views/app/group/addGroup.tpl.html',
            controller: function($scope) {

                $scope.addNew = function(formObj) {
                    console.log(formObj)
                }
            }
};
```

This form shows up in a modal. A regular bootstrap modal. Not the bootstrap angular ui modal.

When I submit the form, I don't get the values of the input. Though I get a form object. The form should create a local object with the name of the form i.e. myForm and I should be able to access input values with the dot operator i.e. myForm.name

The logged object in console is like this.[image: It doesn't show the "name" property]

I don't understand why isn't it working.

Update:

The directive is shown inside a div using ngInclude.

Comment: Are you inside ng-controller(can't see) ? And where is `ng-model` to bind data with the scope variables

Comment: It seems like I need to use `ng-model` in each of the input fields to get the value in the form. Thanks.

Comment: in ur case it will be like `<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" ng-model="GroupForm.name" required>` because you are passing `GroupForm` object to the controller